# HTTP Status 500: Invalid property [Set<Object>] of bean class [DTO]: Illegal attempt to get property threw exception

Tags: reactjs, spring, http, jpa, axios

I am working with React and Axios and trying to pass data through the `PutMapping` Spring function below:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(
            @PathVariable("id") final String id, final ObjectDTO updatedData) {
        Optional<ObjectDTO> oldRecord = objectService.findRecord(id);
        try {
            objectService.update(oldRecord.get(), updatedData);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(e, HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        }
    }
```

The DTO I am passing in may have a populated Set of other objects in it `(others)`. The set comes from a table referenced in its entity.

```
import java.util.Set;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class ObjectDTO {

    /** the first code column. */
    private String first;

    /** the second code column. */
    private String second;

    /** the others column. */
    private Set<Other> others;
}
```

I am getting the HTTP 500 error with the message:

```
Invalid property [others] of bean class [ObjectDTO]: Illegal attempt to get property 'others' threw exception
```

With this happening, how can I pass the DTO into the function without throwing this error? I don't need to use the set that's causing the exception in the following functions. However the set is crucial for the DTO.

I have tried implementing a constructor in the DTO and the entity that's referenced in the DTO, but that did not work. There isn't much documentation on the issue.

Comment: Why not show the ObjectDTO java definition? The error should show a stack and likely a cause that might help identify the problem more specifically - it isn't clear if this error is occurring on the update method signature deserializing JSON data into your ObjectDTO or if it is on the findRecord call. I'd guess you have private access on the set/get methods - just cause your app doesn't need to get that data doesn't mean your serialization process won't need it.

Comment: Based on what I am seeing, it is occurring on the network. It's not even reaching the controller method I posted inside the original post. Additionally, the variables in the DTO are all private.

Comment: The client doesn't convert the data to an ObjectDTO does it? What you see is the error returned. The error stack will show you what and where the problem is exactly occurring; look at the server logs and ensure you are actually sending the error, not just its message back to the client (or don't, as the client doesn't usually care - but you will when debugging issues!). Make the fields public or the accessors public so your serialization processor (Jackson?) can use them.

Comment: You must show the contents of `ObjectDTO` and the payload you are sending.  Please read through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I will update my question with an example. I cannot show the true code for privacy reasons.